# OpenCV on Xcode running overlap windows

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv

When I run OpenCV on Xcode that have multiple windows, it shows all windows in the same position (overlap).
Normally I have to drag them all from the Mission Control screen with a mouse.
Does it has a way to make it show one beside another(not overlap)?

[image][image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**, there is.

With [`cv::moveWindow()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#movewindow) you can move a window to a specific position.

> void **moveWindow**(const string& *winname*, int *x*, int *y*)
>
> **Parameters**:
>   *winname* – Window name
>   *x* – The new x-coordinate of the window
>   *y* – The new y-coordinate of the window

Comment: Another solution is to use a [Mac OS X app](http://www.sjonsson.com/2011/01/easily-arrange-and-size-windows-on-mac.html) for that.